# Regex to replace a content inside HTML page

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex, replace

I need to remove the following string content from a HTML page

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/terminaldeembarque.wordpress.com/1847/"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/terminaldeembarque.wordpress.com/2044/"></a>
```

Note that only the numbers "2044" and "1847" are variables, can I do that with a regex?
Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex:

```
"a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/terminaldeembarque.wordpress.com/[0-9]*/\"><img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/terminaldeembarque.wordpress.com/[0-9]*/\"></a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want to remove all anchor tags or just a specific one.
You could place this whole string into a regular expression (don't forget to escape everything) and instead of the numbers "2044" and "1847" use \d{0,} or \d+ like so:

```
...wordpress.com/\d+/
```

or

```
...wordpress.com/\d{0,}/
```

Change the zero in {0,} to the minimum required amount of digits to match.
But be aware of that this regex is very specific and will break if one char is different from what you supplied. For example if rel attribute is omitted or any other change in html structure.

**Final regex:**

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds\.wordpress\.com/1\.0/gocomments/terminaldeembarque\.wordpress\.com/\d{0,}/"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds\.wordpress\.com/1\.0/comments/terminaldeembarque\.wordpress\.com/\d{0,}/"></a>
```